# Unable to deserialize property with specific name

Tags: c#, serialization, datacontractserializer

I'm using `DataContractSerializer` in C# to deserialize xml file into object, and everything was working fine :)

My issue started when I add a new property to my class and xml file. My new property name is `EncryptionKey` every time I deserialize file, property value remain `null`, but when i change the name of xml element and property to `anEncryptionKey` it deserialized correctly without changing anything else in the code.

Actually I try a lot of options for property name like `EncryptKey`, `Encrypt` and a lot more but I ended up with `anEncryptionKey`.

Maybe there is some constraint on properties names or something like that or I just need more caffeine to figure it out.

Xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<KioskSettings xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Proxies" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <ID>20198</ID>
  <HeartBeatInterval>1</HeartBeatInterval>
  <ServerURL></ServerURL>
  <EncryptionKey>abcd</EncryptionKey>
</KioskSettings>
```

Code i use to deserialize file into object:

```
private KioskSettings ReadEngineSettingsFromSimulatorXmlFile()
 {
    KioskSettings engineSettings = new KioskSettings();
    DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(KioskSettings));
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"c:\simulation.xml", FileMode.Open);
    XmlDictionaryReader reader = XmlDictionaryReader.CreateTextReader(fs, new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas());
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        switch (reader.NodeType)
        {
            case XmlNodeType.Element:
                if (serializer.IsStartObject(reader))
                {
                    engineSettings = (KioskSettings)serializer.ReadObject(reader);
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    fs.Flush(); fs.Close();
    reader.Close(); 
    reader = null;
    serializer = null;
    return engineSettings;
}
```

KioskSettings class:

```
 public class KioskSettings
 {
    public string ID { get; set; }

    public int HeartBeatInterval {get; set;}

    public string ServerURL {get; set;}

    public string EncryptionKey { get; set; }

 }
```

Note: Above code may contains some syntax errors because I modify it to make it short.

Comment: try adding [DataMember] :)

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, actually deserialization is working fine for all other properties except 'EncryptionKey' without adding '[DataMember]' attribute, When I add it to 'EncryptionKey' property only it has been deserialized correctly but when I add it to remaining properties unfortunately it does not deserialized again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ensure your XML nodes are in alphabetical order:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<KioskSettings xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Proxies" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <EncryptionKey>abcd</EncryptionKey>
  <HeartBeatInterval>1</HeartBeatInterval>
  <ID>20198</ID>
  <ServerURL></ServerURL>
</KioskSettings>
```

Serialize a KioskSettings object with the following code, and ensure your XML takes the same form:

```
public static string DataContractSerializeObject<T>(T objectToSerialize)
{
    using (MemoryStream memStm = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
        serializer.WriteObject(memStm, objectToSerialize);

        memStm.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(memStm))
        {
            string result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

If you need to preserve a specific order then specify the `DataMember` attribute on your class properties - [Data Member Order](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms729813%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) e.g.

```
[DataContract]
public class KioskSettings
{
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public string ID { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 2)]
    public int HeartBeatInterval { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 3)]
    public string ServerURL { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 4)]
    public string EncryptionKey { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for code examples, but i think that above code is used to serialization, I have trouble only with deserialization. I do not need to serialize into file as it will be edited manually as file is just for simulation purposes.

Comment: OK, then just specify the DataMember attribute as mentioned at the bottom of my answer. Have a look at the documentation link for more details.

Comment: I will check documentation, but i try DataMember attribute before and it does not solve issue

Comment: Using the DataMember Order attribute works fine me for. I've updated the solution to show the updated KioskSettings class.

Comment: Sorry for my late replay, yes using DisplayOrder solve issue. Thanks